# Make div disapear after a while

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, javascript, jquery

I have made a page, where if the user update its form, the backend will send the user back to the form with a message like this:

```
header('loaction:/index.php?msg');
```

On the index.php site, it loads this:

```
if(isset[$_GET['msg'] {
$message = 'Updated';
echo '<div class="update_message">'.$message.'</div>';
};
```

This works fine, but I would like the message to fade out after a couple of seconds. I tried this, but wouldn't fade out:

```
if(isset[$_GET['msg'] {
$message = 'Updated';
echo '<div class="update_message">'.$message.'</div>';
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function() {
$('div.update_message').hide().fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
})
</script>";
    };
```

The message still apears but it doesn't fade out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a jQuery snippet but have you actually loaded the jQuery library?

You can do do by using: `JHtml::_('jquery.framework');`

Here is the updated code with some modifications:

```
$msg = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('msg');

if (isset($msg))
{
    echo '<div id="update_message">Updated</div>';

    JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
    JFactory::getDocument()->addScriptDeclaration('
        jQuery(function($) {
            $('#update_message').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
        });
    ');
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Should this still be inside a `<script>` ? Haven't worked with jQuery ever :D

Comment: Arh I made it work :) Only thing I needed to edit, was the " instead of ' after `addScriptDeclaration(` and again at last :)

Comment: No need to use a `<script>` tag here as the `addScriptDeclaration` function will automatically insert it inside that tag for you ;)